can we use the spread operator for merging the array?
take the two variables a and b as a two different arrays the variable c shows the output in only one array that means this method merges the two or more arrays into a single array
let a=[a ,b];
let b=[c ,d];

c=[a,...b]

the output will be
c= [[a,b],c,d]

if we deep clone the a and b at a time the output will be
c=[...a,...b]

c=[a,b,c,d]


let a=[a,b]; will give you an error can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization - did you not notice the error when you ran this code?

If you want to have the items of array a as well, you need to spread it too: c=[...a, ...b] 

yes, when we want to spread it for a the output will be c= [a,b,c,d]

@JaromandaX when we get an error take it as a const

which would result in the same error ... what is your quest?

@JaromandaX declare a before you initializes the value

Right, so why didn't you show code you are actually working with rather than invalid code?

@JaromandaX i this is my first question,i cant repeat this next time anyway thank you

You can spread both arrays in order to get merged one single dimentional array
let a=["a","b"];
let b=["c","d"];
c=[...a,...b]

output
c = ["a", "b", "c","d"];

Spread operator in javascript spreads contents of Array and Objects,
So, writing
const a = [1,2,3,4];
...a // means 1,2,3,4 (without wrapper array)

you can use these spreaded elements,
In a Function as arguments
function sum(a,b,c,d){
 return a+b+c+d;
}
const nums = [1,2,3,4];
const result = sum(...nums); // becomes ->  sum(1,2,3,4);

To Form Another Array
const nums = [1,2,3,4];
const nums2 = [...nums, 5,6,7,8]; // -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

You can also create object
const nums = [1,2,3,4];
const obj = {...nums};

/*
Output

{
  "1":1,
  "2":2,
  "3":3,
  "4":4
}

*/


And Many more things

If you want merge array a & b you should use spread like this:
let c=[...a,...b]

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
let combinedArray= [...array1, ...array2];
console.log(combinedArray); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
